# ros::init() must be called before creating a node handle

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node-handle, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have defined a library (i.e. another ROS package) that node "X" depends upon. In the header file of the library I have a class that declares a node handle. When "X" is being preprocessed, the library's header file is pulled into "X".

When I run the system (via roslaunch), I immediately get this: "ros::init() must be called before creating a node handle" and the node crashes b/c it finds the node handle before it finds main(), which is where ros::init is called.

The question: How do I allow a node handle to exist in the library header file (so the library class can use it) without causing such an error?

Here is an example:

Lib.h:

```
class Z
{
     public: ...
     private: ros::NodeHandle nh;
};
```

Node "X" source (.cpp):

```
#include <Lib/Lib.h>
...
main()
{
     Z z;
     ros::init(...);
}
```

When I launch "X", which depends upon Lib (and by extension "Z"), the node handle is found before ros::init() is executed, even though the node handle is not used until afterwards...

Again, the runtime error is: "ros::init() must be called before creating a node handle"

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32510/ros::init()-must-be-called-before-creating-a-node-handle/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is nothing wrong with your example as described; in fact it's a typical usage. The `NodeHandle` is not created until you create the instance of `Z`, which happens after the call to `ros::init()`, so there should be no problem.

Most likely you are declaring a global instance of `Z` (or some other class containing a `NodeHandle`) either in your `main.cpp` or in the library. Since globals are created before `main()`, `ros::init()` has not yet been called and you get the error.

Get a stack trace from the failed assertion to see where the `NodeHandle` is being created.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2012-04-24**:
That makes sense. Would is work to create a node handle/publisher in a member function of Z, and then call the member function to publish something? The reason I'm not just creating Z after init() is because I need Z to be global so that anything (classes included) in node "X" can access it...

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-11-25**:
I have the same problem you mentioned ^

Could you tell me how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to control when the constructor for `Z` runs, you can make it a `boost::shared_ptr` (even a global one) and then wait until after the `ros::init()` before allocating it.

```
boost::shared_ptr<Z> z;
main()
{
  ros::init(...);
  z.reset(new Z());
  ...
}
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2012-04-24**:
Using this approaches seems to forbid me from using member functions of Z... for example, using the above syntax, and then calling z.foo() from within a class in node "X" gives the error that "boost::shared_ptr does not contain function foo"

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-24**:
It's now a pointer, so the call looks like z->foo().

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally, using kind a fixed [Major's](http://answers.ros.org/question/32510/rosinit-must-be-called-before-creating-a-node-handle/?answer=132086#post-id-132086) version:

```
class ROSCommonNode
{
protected:
    ROSCommonNode(int argc, char **argv, const char *node_name)
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, node_name);
    }
};

class ROSCommonWorker : ROSCommonNode
{
public:
    ROSCommonWorker(int argc, char **argv, const char *node_name) : ROSBaseNode(argc, argv, node_name)
    {
        //register some common publishers/subscribers or deal with global param service, whatever
    }

private:
    ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
};
```

Motivation: couple of duplicated lines of code saved, also centralized way of changing how all of my common nodes/services/workers/etc. works with logging/dealing with parameters/etc.

---

Originally posted by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) with karma: 91 on 2014-02-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-24**:
This seems like a really complicated way to wrap calling ros::init as the first line in main(). Is the Base/Common node a singleton?

**Comment by [Kamiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/5346/kamiccolo/) on 2014-02-24**:
In the context of single ROS node - it's a  singleton. Not sure if You were asking that and I understood the question right. The main idea is - why the hell I need to initiate each Node by hand in `main()` if I can wrap it like that and forget? EDIT: fixed a few typos in the code.

**Comment by [major](https://answers.ros.org/users/12276/major/) on 2014-02-24**:
class ROSCommonNode should have a constructer named ROSCommonNode() instead of ROSBaseNode()
but it i like this solution  to inherate from this basenode.

**Comment by [major](https://answers.ros.org/users/12276/major/) on 2014-02-24**:
I think dornehege question about the singleton is becaus of using more nodes so everytime ros::init is called.
maybe a static variable (static int is_inited = 0;) or a static mutex could solve this and an IF -Statement in constructer could solve this to get a singleton behavior ...

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-02-24**:
You can't also forget about this one as you still need to initialize your RosCommonWorker node.